# How to do edit in mysql using JSP page?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

This is EmployeeDao.java file.

```
public Employee getEmployeeById(String employeeId){
    System.out.println("IN getEmployeeById");
    Employee employee = new Employee();
    try {
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement("select * from login where email=?");
        preparedStatement.setString(1, employeeId);
        ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
        System.out.println(rs);
        if(rs.next()){
            employee.setFirstname(rs.getString("firstName"));
            System.out.println(""+employee.getFirstname());
            employee.setLastname(rs.getString("lastName"));
            System.out.println(""+employee.getLastname());
            employee.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
            System.out.println(""+employee.getEmail());
            employee.setStatus(rs.getBoolean("status"));
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return employee;    
}
```

This is the EmployeeController.java file.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String forward = "";
    String action = request.getParameter("action");

    if(action.equalsIgnoreCase("delete")){
        String employeeId = request.getParameter("employeeId");
        dao.deleteEmployee(employeeId);
        forward = employee_listing ;
        request.setAttribute("employees", dao.getAllEmployees());
    }else if(action.equalsIgnoreCase("edit")){
        forward = employee_detail ;
        String employeeId = request.getParameter("employeeId");
        Employee employee = dao.getEmployeeById(employeeId);
        request.setAttribute("employee", employee);
    }else if(action.equalsIgnoreCase("listEmployee")){
        forward = employee_listing;
        request.setAttribute("employees", dao.getAllEmployees());
    }
    else{
        forward = dashboard;
    }

    RequestDispatcher view  = request.getRequestDispatcher(forward);
    view.forward(request, response);
}
```

This is the employee-detail page.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="EmployeeController" name="frmAddEmployee">  
                                <% 
                                    String action = request.getParameter("action");
                                    System.out.println(action);
                                %>
                                    <% while (rs.next()) { %>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="" class="col-sm-4 control-label">First Name</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" value="<%= rs.getString("firstName") %>" >
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Last Name</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" value="<%= rs.getString("lastName") %>"  >
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Email</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                                      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="" value="<%= rs.getString("email") %>" >
                                      <% } %>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Employee Status</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                                        <label class="switch">
                                            <input type="checkbox" checked>
                                            <div class="slider round"></div>
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-primary"> &nbsp; <input type="reset" name="cancel" value="Cancel" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
```

So when I clicked on edit button it will be redirect to employee-detail page and I got the specific employee detail.

But after edit that particular employee detail and clicked on "update" button,
I got the white screen and nothing else.
And that page url is ::
"http://localhost:8000/SampleLogin/EmployeeController"

So How can I solved this and move on.

Comment: Look at @Ninja Coder answer - he is right, and at least you have a mistake in the html. And for cleaner coding practice it is better to separate processing of read and write requests between doGet and doPost methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is replace

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-primary">
```

with : <`input type="submit" name="action" value="edit" class="btn btn-primary">`

Comment: It won't fix the original problem because **doGet** couldn't be reached with **POST** method

Comment: doPost called inside doGet if  not relaced auto generated stub. There no input parameter named with action in his  jsp so he just need to replace his edit button name and value

Comment: But doPost doesn't call doGet, and servlet receives doPost

Comment: Ah, doGet is called from doPost if he extended DefaultServlet class

Answer (score 0):

First of all - do not use **doGet** for update data.

Your form method is **POST**:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" ...>
```

So you need to do all the update magick inside **doPost** method of your controller.

Here are some useful tips about CRUD with servlets - https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info